# Google Chrome crashed after updating

Tags: networking, google-chrome

I updated my google chrome to v56 from v53,After updating the chrome I am Unable to search or use chrome.when I try to search or open a URL chrome shows me that **Your connection is not private**.
Guys Can anyone help me to solve this issue...[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I already checked that...but not date problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because of missing Network Security Service library because of upgrade to chrome 56.

To install it run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the above error message appears in your Google Chrome browser because there is a problem with the SSL connection, and your browser can't verify the SSL certificate. SSL is a secure method to encrypt data from your computer (in this case, it's your browser) and send to the server, help to keep the information private and safe while transmitting - and opposite.

With this SSL error, it means your computer or current internet connection prevents the Google Chrome browser to load the requested website with a private and secure method.

Fix Your Connection Is Not Private Error In Google Chrome using the following [link](https://usefulpcguide.com/16666/your-connection-is-not-private/)>

I hope this information helps;.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you are attempting to access a Wifi network that has a sign-in portal.

Go to any website starting with http:// like http://google.com

On the portal sign-in page that opens, sign in to use the Internet.

There are other possibilities listed in the Source (cited below) but the above is the most likely.

Source:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6098869?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing [Your Connection is Not Private error](https://www.gadgetvstech.com/your-connection-is-not-private-android/) in chrome then try these solutions :

1. Update your Date & Time
2. Uninstall antivirus or Security application
3. Open incognito window on chrome browser
4. Clear browsing data and cache of chrome browser
5. Factory Data Reset Your Phone